# Multicolumn Output

Tags: list-manipulation

The code

```
Multicolumn[
 Table[{Prime[i], First[PrimitiveRootList[Prime[i]]]}, {i, 1, 100}],
  5]
```

yields 5 columns of primes 2, ...,541, each paired with its least positive primitive root (LPR).  I wish to display the output without curly braces or commas in 10 columns with 20 rows.  The desired output is shown below.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: desired output]

Comment: Multicolumn generates a Grid. You can postedit using  /. {a_, b_} :> Sequence[a, b]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) every row of the grid object produced by `MultiColumn` using [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[Flatten, 
  Multicolumn[Table[{Prime[i], First[PrimitiveRootList[Prime[i]]]}, {i, 1, 100}], 5] , 
  {1, All}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`FlattenAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlattenAt.html):

```
FlattenAt[Tuples[{{1}, Range[100/5], Range[5]}]] @ 
 Multicolumn[Table[{Prime[i], First[PrimitiveRootList[Prime[i]]]}, {i, 1, 100}], 5]
```

> same picture

You can also transform each pair `{a, b}` in the table into a [`Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) separated by [`Spacer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacer.html):

```
Multicolumn[Table[
  Row[{Prime[i], First[PrimitiveRootList[Prime[i]]]}, Spacer[1]],
  {i, 1, 100}], 5]
```

[image]